# CPU TIMER Interrupt and SIGXCPU Signal

Tags: operating-system, signals, cpu, interrupt

This question is based on my understanding as follows.

(1) Signal and interrupt are different things. Interrupt is communication between the kernel and the CPU, and Signal is communication between the kernel and the process.
(2) If a signal is delivered during the execution of a process, The process handles the signal at the next schedule, not immediately.

While looking at the Signal list, I found a signal called SIGXCPU. It is written that the signal is delivered when CPU time limit exceeded.

By the way, Wasn't the CPU timer expiration event an Interrupt, not a Signal? Why is Signal delivered to the process additionally?

As I studied, when the CPU timer exceeded, the CPU control of process A is taken away and the context switch occurs to process B. On the other hand, the SIGXCPU signal is transmitted to processA.

So even after process A's schedule is finished, SIGXCPU remains in process A's bit vector. The next time process A takes control of the CPU, it must handle this SIGXCPU, but the default action is terminate.

I don't quite understand. Please explain what happens when the CPU TImer expires.

Comment: How would you detect an interrupt in Linux?

Comment: An interrupt is something the CPU does to the kernel; a signal is something the kernel does to a process.